# Gravity and the effect on space time

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature

If you drew a line 1 million kilometers long in space far away from any gravity source and you travel along this line at 1000 kilometres per hour, it takes you 1000 hours to complete the journey.

If then you move this line close to Earth say 100 kilometres above the Earth.

Due to  Earth's  gravity, will this line still be 1 million kilometres long, due to Earth’s gravity curving of spacetime?

Would my journey still take 1000 hours?

Comment: What is this "line"? There is no physical notion of the motion of purely geometric objects, so the answer to this question depends entirely on how you define the meaning of "moving the line".

Comment: The Area of space you would move occupy  to travel the 1000000 kilometers.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically describing the Shapiro effect. If you take a much longer path next to the Sun (that has a lot of stress-energy), and you try to calculate the speed of light from Earth, you will see that it is slower then c, due to two reasons:

1. next to the Sun, clocks will seem to run slower then on Earth (relatively)
2. the path that light has to take will seem to be a little bit longer, due to the same reason that you are trying to describe

This is only true when you measure clocks from far away, but if you try to measure clocks at the Sun, you will see that light seems to move at speed c in vacuum when measured locally always.

Yes, what you are trying to describe is an effect of gravity, where we use the phrase "gravity bends spacetime". In this case what really happens is that all particles that we know about, will have an altered trajectory when they interact with the gravitational field, so we say that the gravitational field has an effect on spacetime so that in that area of spacetime all the particles that we know about will have an altered trajectory as they interact with the gravitational field.

Since gravity is only attractive, this trajectory seems to be always inward curved towards the gravitational center.

Now instead of the photons, you are using a spaceship that is trying to travel along a straight (in 3D) path next to the Earth. As your spaceship starts to interact with the gravitational field of the Earth, its path will be altered so that the trajectory will be curved inwards toward the center of Earth. In reality, your spaceship is trying to move along a geodesic, that is the shortest path in 4D spacetime.

So in your case if you try to measure the time elapsed along the journey on your own clock on the spaceship, you will see it is ticking normally, and it will be the same amount. It is only when you try to measure the time elapsed on a far away observer's clock, that you will see it takes longer (because the far away observer's clock ticks relatively faster considering it is in space where there is less stress-energy).

As per the correct comments, the analogy is as per your question that you are asking about a spaceship traveling a distance in a gravitational field, that will be "bent" by gravity, and you are asking how long the travel time will be. The Shapiro effect describes this effect of gravity on a massless particle, but it is true for massive particles, and an object, the spaceship too.

Comment: The Shapiro effect is about the delay in travel time of electromagnetic waves. It is not evident at all what it has to do with this question, which doesn't even mention light/electromagnetic waves.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the Shapiro has two effects, and that includes the travel distance and the time elapsed. The gravitational zone has an effect on both massless and massive particles. In the question it is an object, a spaceship. The rest should be analogous. I hope i wrote this down in a understandable way but maybe I need to edit that. Thanks for your comment I will try to explain more.